# CSS z-index and jquery effects

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

It is possible to animate images whit z-index like opacity and others?!

Because i can't get it right

```
  On click get id clicked and to the following to the img id equal to clicked id
 $('#gallery img').eq(atrb-1).css("z-index",z++).slideUp('slow');
```

But it display the image whit lower z index

### How i can avoid that?

Yep is at the start of javascript
The problem is not the z-index but the z-index jquery animation like fade and other

```
 $("#gallery img").each(function() {
      z++;
     $(this).css('z-index', z).attr('id',z);//set z index and id

    $('#bar').append("<a href='#' id="+z+"/>");

});
```

When i click on a link from the #bar the image  whit the id of link is in front of others

**Found the answer : it was fadeToggle to hide all elements and use it again to fadein hidden elements :)))**

Comment: Did you declare `z` anywhere?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish?  Are you trying to gradually increase the z-index to bring an image to the front?

Comment: It can be done, but it won't do what you think. jQuery's `.animate()` just means "go from A to B by taking each step in between very quickly". Z-indexes are still discreet, something is either on top of something else, or not.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, although it will still be a discrete transition between different z-indexes. So I can't really imagine a scenario where this would do anything useful --maybe a pile of objects with different indexes?

It looks like you're trying to "increment" the z-index by one, that can be done, but would be useless. That's like "animating" between width:100px and width:101px

```
$('#gallery img').eq(atrb-1).animate("z-index",'+=1').slideUp('slow');
```